# Remove a single ROS package

Tags: ros, calibration, ros-kinetic, packages, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm still trying to solve [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/296087/camera_calibration-opens-gui-window-but-freezes/) problem in another question.  I decided to uninstall camera_calibration and install it again, see if that helps. However if I try to remove the package with apt-get it also wants to remove the whole ROS! what's the correct way of removing a single package? see output below:

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-kinetic-camera-calibration
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaprutil1-dev libboost-all-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-filesystem-dev
  libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-system-dev
  libboost-thread-dev libboost-wave-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libgazebo7-dev
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libgtk2.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev
  libharfbuzz-gobject0 libinput-dev liblog4cxx-dev liblog4cxx10-dev libmirclient-dev
  libmircommon-dev libmircookie-dev libmircookie2 libmircore-dev libogre-1.9-dev
  libpango1.0-dev libpcl-dev libpyside2-dev libqt5opengl5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev
  libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-private-dev
  libsdformat4-dev liburdfdom-dev libvtk6-qt-dev libwayland-bin libwayland-dev
  qtbase5-dev qtbase5-private-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-private-dev
  qtmultimedia5-dev qtscript5-dev qtscript5-private-dev qttools5-dev
  qttools5-private-dev ros-kinetic-actionlib ros-kinetic-actionlib-msgs
  ros-kinetic-actionlib-tutorials ros-kinetic-bond ros-kinetic-bond-core
  ros-kinetic-bondcpp ros-kinetic-bondpy ros-kinetic-camera-calibration-parsers
  ros-kinetic-camera-info-manager ros-kinetic-class-loader ros-kinetic-collada-parser
  ros-kinetic-collada-urdf ros-kinetic-common-msgs ros-kinetic-common-tutorials
  ros-kinetic-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport
  ros-kinetic-control-msgs ros-kinetic-cpp-common ros-kinetic-cv-bridge
  ros-kinetic-depth-image-proc ros-kinetic-desktop ros-kinetic-diagnostic-aggregator
  ros-kinetic-diagnostic-analysis ros-kinetic-diagnostic-common-diagnostics
  ros-kinetic-diagnostic-msgs ros-kinetic-diagnostic-updater ros-kinetic-diagnostics
  ros-kinetic-dynamic-reconfigure ros-kinetic-eigen-conversions
  ros-kinetic-executive-smach ros-kinetic-filters ros-kinetic-gazebo-dev
  ros-kinetic-gazebo-msgs ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros
  ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-kinetic-geometric-shapes ros-kinetic-geometry
  ros-kinetic-geometry-msgs ros-kinetic-geometry-tutorials ros-kinetic-image-common
  ros-kinetic-image-geometry ros-kinetic-image-proc ros-kinetic-image-publisher
  ros-kinetic-image-rotate ros-kinetic-image-transport
  ros-kinetic-image-transport-plugins ros-kinetic-image-view
  ros-kinetic-interactive-marker-tutorials ros-kinetic-interactive-markers
  ros-kinetic-joint-state-publisher ros-kinetic-kdl-conversions ros-kinetic-kdl-parser
  ros-kinetic-laser-assembler ros-kinetic-laser-filters ros-kinetic-laser-geometry
  ros-kinetic-laser-pipeline ros-kinetic-librviz-tutorial ros-kinetic-map-msgs
  ros-kinetic-message-filters ros-kinetic-message-runtime ros-kinetic-mk
  ros-kinetic-nav-msgs ros-kinetic-nodelet ros-kinetic-nodelet-core
  ros-kinetic-nodelet-topic-tools ros-kinetic-nodelet-tutorial-math ros-kinetic-opencv3
  ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs ros-kinetic-pcl-ros
  ros-kinetic-perception-pcl ros-kinetic-pluginlib ros-kinetic-pluginlib-tutorials
  ros-kinetic-polled-camera ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding ros-kinetic-qt-dotgraph
  ros-kinetic-qt-gui ros-kinetic-qt-gui-cpp ros-kinetic-qt-gui-py-common
  ros-kinetic-random-numbers ros-kinetic-resource-retriever ros-kinetic-robot
  ros-kinetic-robot-model ros-kinetic-robot-state-publisher ros-kinetic-ros
  ros-kinetic-ros-base ros-kinetic-ros-comm ros-kinetic-ros-core
  ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials ros-kinetic-rosbag ros-kinetic-rosbag-storage
  ros-kinetic-rosbuild ros-kinetic-rosconsole ros-kinetic-rosconsole-bridge
  ros-kinetic-roscpp ros-kinetic-roscpp-core ros-kinetic-roscpp-serialization
  ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits ros-kinetic-roscpp-tutorials ros-kinetic-rosgraph-msgs
  ros-kinetic-roslaunch ros-kinetic-roslib ros-kinetic-roslisp ros-kinetic-rosmsg
  ros-kinetic-rosnode ros-kinetic-rosout ros-kinetic-rospack ros-kinetic-rospy
  ros-kinetic-rospy-tutorials ros-kinetic-rosservice ros-kinetic-rostest
  ros-kinetic-rostime ros-kinetic-rostopic ros-kinetic-rosunit ros-kinetic-roswtf
  ros-kinetic-rqt-action ros-kinetic-rqt-bag ros-kinetic-rqt-bag-plugins
  ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins ros-kinetic-rqt-console ros-kinetic-rqt-dep
  ros-kinetic-rqt-graph ros-kinetic-rqt-gui ros-kinetic-rqt-gui-cpp
  ros-kinetic-rqt-gui-py ros-kinetic-rqt-image-view ros-kinetic-rqt-launch
  ros-kinetic-rqt-logger-level ros-kinetic-rqt-moveit ros-kinetic-rqt-msg
  ros-kinetic-rqt-nav-view ros-kinetic-rqt-plot ros-kinetic-rqt-pose-view
  ros-kinetic-rqt-publisher ros-kinetic-rqt-py-common ros-kinetic-rqt-py-console
  ros-kinetic-rqt-reconfigure ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-dashboard
  ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-monitor ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-plugins
  ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-steering ros-kinetic-rqt-runtime-monitor ros-kinetic-rqt-rviz
  ros-kinetic-rqt-service-caller ros-kinetic-rqt-shell ros-kinetic-rqt-srv
  ros-kinetic-rqt-tf-tree ros-kinetic-rqt-top ros-kinetic-rqt-topic ros-kinetic-rqt-web
  ros-kinetic-rviz ros-kinetic-rviz-plugin-tutorials ros-kinetic-rviz-python-tutorial
  ros-kinetic-self-test ros-kinetic-sensor-msgs ros-kinetic-shape-msgs
  ros-kinetic-simulators ros-kinetic-smach-msgs ros-kinetic-smach-ros ros-kinetic-stage
  ros-kinetic-stage-ros ros-kinetic-std-msgs ros-kinetic-std-srvs
  ros-kinetic-stereo-image-proc ros-kinetic-stereo-msgs ros-kinetic-tf
  ros-kinetic-tf-conversions ros-kinetic-tf2 ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen
  ros-kinetic-tf2-geometry-msgs ros-kinetic-tf2-kdl ros-kinetic-tf2-msgs
  ros-kinetic-tf2-py ros-kinetic-tf2-ros ros-kinetic-theora-image-transport
  ros-kinetic-topic-tools ros-kinetic-trajectory-msgs ros-kinetic-turtle-actionlib
  ros-kinetic-turtle-tf ros-kinetic-turtle-tf2 ros-kinetic-turtlesim ros-kinetic-urdf
  ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial ros-kinetic-vision-opencv
  ros-kinetic-visualization-marker-tutorials ros-kinetic-visualization-msgs
  ros-kinetic-visualization-tutorials ros-kinetic-viz ros-kinetic-xacro
  ros-kinetic-xmlrpcpp
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  ros-kinetic-camera-calibration* ros-kinetic-desktop-full* ros-kinetic-image-pipeline*
  ros-kinetic-perception*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 4 to remove and 11 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 238 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296193/remove-a-single-ros-package/) by [martinakos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36215/martinakos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there martina,
the packages won't be removed it just says:

> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

The only packages that will be removed are the ones under:

> The following packages will be REMOVED

Meaning only these ones:
`ros-kinetic-camera-calibration* ros-kinetic-desktop-full* ros-kinetic-image-pipeline* ros-kinetic-perception*`

I think you are having the issue because you are using purge, try to use: `sudo apt remove ros-kinetic-camera-calibration`

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martinakos](https://answers.ros.org/users/36215/martinakos/) on 2018-07-04**:
I get the same output with remove, instead of purge

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-07-04**:
Still, as I said, it won't remove all of ROS, just those packages `ros-kinetic-camera-calibration* ros-kinetic-desktop-full* ros-kinetic-image-pipeline* ros-kinetic-perception*`
In the end, just go for it, I've reinstalled ROS maaany times and doing a reinstall is the way to go.

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-07-04**:
I wonder, why do you need to remove camera calibration? Do you need to reinstall it?

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2019-12-06**:
so what is the safest and cleanest way to do so after all?